# Authenticating Pusher using React Native and a Laravel Backend

Tags: javascript, laravel, reactjs, react-native, pusher

Im trying to authenticate a private broadcast using the following React Native script.

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import Pusher from 'pusher-js/react-native';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    Pusher.logToConsole = true;
    var pusher = new Pusher('*********', {
      authEndpoint: 'http://app.pgm/api/authtest',
      cluster: 'eu',
      encrypted: true
    });

    const channel = pusher.subscribe('private-chat-1');

  }
```

The above is being posted to the function below, the function below returns an auth token when tested from Postman. However when I run the app through React Native I get the following response.

```
  public function pusher(Request $request){
        $pusher = new Pusher(config('broadcasting.connections.pusher.key'), config('broadcasting.connections.pusher.secret'), config('broadcasting.connections.pusher.app_id'));

        echo $pusher->socket_auth($request->channel_name, $request->socket_id);
  }
```

> [exp] Pusher : Couldn't retrieve authentication info. 0Clients must be authenticated to join private or presence channels. See: https://pusher.com/docs/authenticating_users
>   [exp] Pusher : No callbacks on private-chat-1 for pusher:subscription_error

It leads me to think Laravel isn't receiving the post data. I do not currently have any middleware that could block the request.

Can anyone see where I am going wrong?

Comment: Have you find any solution for this, I'm facing the same problem

Answer (score 3):

It's working fine on my side on both `Postman` and `React Native` ends. I used following piece of code. In my case I'm not using key `encrypted: true`.

I'm listening event successfully.

**Code**

```
    // Pusher Logging
    Pusher.logToConsole = true;
    
    // Initialization & Configuration
    const pusher = new Pusher('****************', {
      cluster: '***',
      authEndpoint:
        'http://domain/products/chat/public/api/authtest',
    });

    // Making Connection
    pusher.connection.bind('connected', function (data) {
      console.log(data.socket_id);
    });

    // Subscribe Channel
    var channel = pusher.subscribe('private-channel-name', (data) => {
      console.log('Subscribe Channel');
      console.log(data);
    });

    // Accessing Channel
    const channelInfo = pusher.channel('private-chatify');
    console.log('channel Info');
    console.log(channelInfo);

    // Listen Event
    channel.bind('yourevent', function (data) {
      console.log('An event was triggered with message');
      console.log(data);
      console.log(data.message);
    });
```

Hope it may help you.